# NSRangeException using sortedArrayUsingComparator

Tags: objective-c, nsrangeexception

I am sometimes seeing this exception in Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[__NSArrayM getObjects:range:]: range {0, 6294} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 6292]
-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]
-[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:] + 284
```

I understand the message, but unfortunately I cannot find a reproducible sequence or root cause, though it seems to occur more often with larger data sets.

This is the related code that does the sorting, where the crash is occuring:

```
NSMutableArray *contacts = ...; // loaded from another method, in an NSOperation
NSArray *result = [contacts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Contact *obj1, Contact *obj2) {
        return [obj1.fullName compare:obj2.fullName];
    }];
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: Here is a pastebin of the full exception from Crashlytics - http://pastebin.com/T2haqCWX

Comment: Is the array getting mutated by any thread at the time the sorting happens?

Comment: This is immutable array, mutable copy is created internally for sorting and cannot be accessed by anyone else, so probably not the case. Edit: realised that didn't see declaration for contacts. Fair point.

Comment: Can you post more info from crabslytics? Pastebin or gist…

Comment: I added a pastebin with the full exception, thanks!

Comment: @SashZats any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like Shanti might be right. Any chance you are mutating the same array from a different thread?